# Echoing PHP in HTML

Tags: php, html

Is there a difference between PHP echoing inside a HTML `<input/>` wrapper and `<textarea/>` wrapper ?

```
 <input id="element_3" name="Portnumber" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $person['portnumber']; ?>"/>
```

echos the data from the portnumber table.

```
 <textarea id="element_5" name="Description" class="element textarea medium" value="<?php echo $person['description']; ?>"></textarea>
```

Nothing is echoed.

**Question**

should the syntax inside text area wrappers be different to the input wrapper in order to display the echo.

Comment: Yes, for textareas the content goes between the tags, not in a value= attribute. Also think of escaping output.

Comment: the content of textarea should be inserted between openning node and closing node. There is no value attribute for a `<textarea>`

Comment: Use `htmlspecialchars()` to properly escape your variable contents.

Comment: wow all the thumbs down whats wrong with my questions lol some peaple its like i shot a baby or something lol

Comment: @bennyboy I believe you got the downvotes because this question does show a lack of research.. If you would have googled this problem, you would have resolved it without having to resort to SO

Comment: @ samuel liew and Daryl Gill, you are correct i didnt look for an answer first on here first my mistake, however i did google i may not have asked in the write way though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Textarea's don't have a value attribute. The content gets wrapped in the `<textarea>` tags:

```
<textarea id="element_5" name="Description" class="element textarea medium">
    <?php echo $person['description']; ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: I like how no HTML escaping seems to be required ;-)

Comment: This is just the basics. Tutorials on how to build php websites can be found elsewhere.

Comment: For someone with your rep I would expect a better answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<textarea id="element_5" name="Description" class="element textarea medium>
<?php echo $person['description']; ?>
</textarea>
```

Textareas are different to your regular inputs, they do not have the `value` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Textarea has no value attribute

```
 <textarea id="element_5" name="Description" class="element textarea medium"><?php echo $person['description']; ?></textarea>
```